# Call method after X time in java

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, netty

I am using java 8 and netty(async), i have client server application.I i want call some method after X time for each channel.

I tried `java.util.TimerTask`, the problem is that the run method wont get any arguments, i want to run the method with argument, how can i run method after X seconds?

I have tried:

```
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyTimer extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        //TODO: read from object 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You just use Timer with [schedule with delay](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long))

```
Timer time= new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //TODO: read from object 
    }
}, delay);
```

> delay - delay in milliseconds..

Answer (score 0):

Use :-

```
public void scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task,
                                long delay,
                                long period)
```

Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-rate execution, beginning after the specified delay. Subsequent executions take place at approximately regular intervals, separated by the specified period.